# How to (automatically) test if WebRTC MediaStream is working?

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

### Background:

I'm developing a system, part of which is a WebRTC video (or audio) calling. The solution includes quite a bit business logic built on top of what the [getUserMedia](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) and [RTCPeerConnection](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html) API-s support. Especially since Firefox and Chrome implement some of the API-s differently(e.g. `MediaStream#getAudioTracks` always returns [] on Firefox).

#### Example of a requirement to test:

Two parties have a running audio-audio call (both sides have been asked and allowed audio stream(access to microphone)). One side wants to upgrade the call to video-video. Certain UI interaction happens - dialogs to the upgrade initiator for confirming his action and upgrade offer to the receiver with both sides allowing the camera access. Eventually video-video call should be established.

### Question:

How to check if the MediaStream instance is in such state that if attached to `<video>` element `src`, then proper signal(video,audio) would be played?

#### Ideas so far

The most basic test would be to check if the `RTCPeerConnection#onstreamadded` gets called. Problem with that is that sometimes the callback gets called with `MediaStream` instance but when attaching it to the `<video>` element, nothing gets shown. It is very likely that it's a mistake on my part and that is what the test should tell me.

Are there some good properties or callbacks on `RTCPeerConnection` or `MediaStream` objects that could tell me when the communication is set up correctly and data is coming through the streams?

Answer (score 0):

Is the video-Element showing a black background and contains a blob in the src-attribute?
If so, be aware that the video-element also has to be treated differently in FF. In Chrome an autoplay-tag (e.g `<video src="blobIsHere" autoplay></video>` ) is enough to start the video. In FF you need to call the .play()-Method of the Element. In addition, the video-element has to be created differently in FF. It should look something like this:

```
    var el = document.getElementById('my-video');
    if(el.mozSrcObject !== undefined) {
        el.mozSrcObject = remoteStream;
        el.play();
    }
```

If you want to add Firefox-support i recommend to use [adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js?r=3905).

To check if the connection is established you could read the ICE-status, i.e.:

```
    con.onaddstream = function(e){
        if(e.srcElement.iceConnectionState === 'connected' &&
           e.srcElement.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
            // attach to video-element
        }
    };
```

Another reason could be that there is only video sended. To find out what kind of media the remote-client is streaming you have to check the remote-SDP for this substring: 'a=recvonly'. If it is present only audio is streamed. Example:

```
con.onaddstream = function(e){
    if (e.target.remoteDescription.sdp.indexOf('a=recvonly') > -1) {
        // video and audio
    }
    else {
        // only audio
    }
}
```

Note: i just found this out because i am trying to do something similar. I am not sure if this is 100% safe and if it fits for all cases (audio AND video / audio only / video only), but it should be worth a try.

Comment: Calling the .play method in FF was helpful, as I've experienced the 'black box behaviour' in Firefox. I'm in the process of writing tests for our WebRTC related business logic. In coming week(s) I'll report back here to give my results. The first approach I'm taking is to assert multiple things in acceptance test (like if certain step in ui is taken, then multiple criterias would have to be passed one of which would be that PeerConnection would have to be created). By doing that I can catch multiple bugs before I even have to start inspecting the stream objects.

Comment: Note that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580405/how-to-determine-a-webrtc-mediastream-only-has-audio contains the correct call to determine if audio only (`stream.getVideoTracks().length`)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution where I made use of the RTCStatsReport Object which can be retrieved by using getStats() on the RTCPeerConnection.

I setup a variable with the bytes received of the inbound-rtp and updated it with an interval every x seconds. If the bytes received stagnate/do not change it means that the stream does not send any data anymore and is most likely broken. Then the reconnection procedure is triggered.

```js
const x = 7000 // seven seconds
let bytesReceived = -1 // init to -1 so reconnect does not get triggered on launch

// Set up interval that checks every x ms
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  // load stats
  rtcConnections.getStats().then(
      (report: RTCStatsReport) => {
          const br = bytesReceived

          // loop through every possible report
          report.forEach(k => {
              // Here it is implemented for the inbound video
              // but of course you can do it analogeous for outbound and audio
              if (k.type === "inbound-rtp" && k.kind === "video") {

                  // if bytes did not change start reconnection procedure and reset interval
                  if (br === k.bytesReceived) {
                      console.log(`Stream does not send any data.`)
                      clearInterval(interval)
                      // Handle reconnection procedure
                  }
                  bytesReceived = k.bytesReceived
              }
          })
      }
  )
}, x)
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCStatsReport) you can find the documentation for the RTCStatsReport.