# How to determine a webrtc mediastream only has audio?

Tags: webrtc

When I receive an onaddstream event from the other side, how can I determine the MediaStream only has audio, no video?

In other words, can I know a MediaStream object only has audio, no video?

Answer (score 3):

```
peer.onaddstream = function (event) {
    var stream = event.stream;

    if (stream.getAudioTracks().length) alert('Peer has audio stream.');
    if (stream.getVideoTracks().length) alert('Peer has video stream.');
};
```